# check if array element value already existed when user input

Tags: c++

How do i check if array already contains a value?

for example, 
Input:1
Output:1

Input:1
Error!: Number existed

Input:2
Output:2

When the user input already existed in the array, it will show error and ask them to input again, until they entered a different value. when a different value is entered, that value will be added to array. if the value entered is same as any element value, it will not be added to the array.

```
int num[5], temp;
bool val = true, existed = false;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    val = true;

        while(val){

            cout << "\nPlease enter a number:";
            cin >> temp;

            for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
                if(temp == num[x]){
                    existed = true;
                }
            }

            if(existed){
                cout << "Number existed";
            } else {
                num[i] = temp;
                cout << "Your number" << num[i];
                val = false; 
            }
        } 

}
```

Comment: It's such a simple thing. Surely you can make some attempt at this yourself. Generally we ask posters to this forum to show the attempt they have made themselves. If you're too shy to do this then you're not so likely to get any help.

Comment: yes i added my attempt above. I am not sure why its not working. probably my logic

Comment: The problem is simply where you placed `bool existed = false;`. Move it so that it's just before the second for loop `bool existed = false; for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){ ...`. You need to set `existed` to false *each* time you test for existence, not just once at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a short function to do the check:

```
bool alreadyExists(int *array, int array_size, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        if (array[i] == value)
            return true; // we found the same value, return true

    return false; // if we get here we have not found it
}
```

Call it with

```
int input = 1;
if alreadyExists(num, 5, input)
{
    printf("already exists\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Ok to add...");
}
```